# How to add mesh to this script I have create to create stairs in real time?

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine

```
Mesh mesh;
public Vector3[] vertices;
int[] triangle;

public Transform StartPoint;
public Transform EndPoint;
public int steps_in_flight = 100;
public float length,height,LOS,HOS,width = 10;//LOS is short for Length Of Stairs and HOS is short for Height Of Stairs
void Start()
{
    mesh = new Mesh();
    mesh.name = "the mesh of the stair";
    GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;
}

void Update()
{
    CreateStair();
    CreateMesh();
    UpdateMesh();
    HOS = (EndPoint.position.y - StartPoint.position.y);
    LOS = (EndPoint.position.z - StartPoint.position.z);
    height = HOS / steps_in_flight * 4;
    length = LOS / steps_in_flight * 4;
}
void CreateStair()
{
    int z = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int i = 0;
    vertices = new Vector3[steps_in_flight];
    for (; i < steps_in_flight;)
    {
        //the positive is for the left and the negative is for the right to make the stair three dimentional
        vertices[i] = new Vector3(StartPoint.position.x + (width / 2), StartPoint.position.y + height * y, StartPoint.position.z + length * z);//positive
        i++;
        vertices[i] = new Vector3(StartPoint.position.x + -(width / 2), StartPoint.position.y + height * y, StartPoint.position.z + length * z);//negative
        y++;//up one unit
        i++;
        vertices[i] = new Vector3(StartPoint.position.x + (width / 2), StartPoint.position.y + height * y, StartPoint.position.z + length * z);//positive
        i++;
        vertices[i] = new Vector3(StartPoint.position.x + -(width / 2), StartPoint.position.y + height * y, StartPoint.position.z + length * z);//negative
        z++;//forward on unit
        i++;
    }
}
void CreateMesh()//idk what is happening here chatgpt gave me this and it didn't work so don't ask the purpose of this i really dk
{
    int numTriangles = steps_in_flight * 6;
    triangle = new int[numTriangles];

    int vert = 0;
    int tris = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < steps_in_flight; y++)
    {
        triangle[tris + 0] = vert;
        triangle[tris + 1] = vert + (int)HOS + 1;
        triangle[tris + 2] = vert + 1;
        triangle[tris + 3] = vert + 1;
        triangle[tris + 4] = vert + (int)HOS + 1;
        triangle[tris + 5] = vert + (int)HOS + 2;

        vert ++;
        tris += 6;
    }
}
void UpdateMesh()
{
    mesh.Clear();
    mesh.vertices = vertices;
    mesh.triangles = triangle;
    mesh.RecalculateBounds();
    mesh.RecalculateNormals();
}
void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    if(vertices == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
    {
        Gizmos.DrawSphere(vertices[i],.1f);
    }
}
```

I tried to ask chatgpt to help me create the `CreateMesh()` function and it gave me something that didn't work so I tried a couple times but also didn't work then I just gave up because I have no idea how mesh creation work. Also the script is kinda garbage because I made it so is there a way to optimise it cause I can only think of making it like this but I can't think of how I can use math to create stairs to optimise it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a fixed amount of steps I would rather go with a maximum height per step and then calculate how many steps you need to cover the Y-delta.

Then per step you need **8** vertices, not only *4* like you have. At best you could decide to make the steps share the two front-bottom / back-top vertices - but it is just way easier to implement using one complete individual cube per step.

Further have in mind that the vertex positions in the `Mesh` are in **local space**!

Here is what I came up with - this simply uses the object itself as start point and only requires one additional `End` object (I would recommend to e.g. nest it as child under this one)

```
public class StairsController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform m_End;

    [SerializeField]
    private MeshFilter m_MeshFilter;

    [SerializeField]
    private MeshCollider m_MeshCollider;

    [SerializeField]
    private float m_MaxStepHeight = 0.5f;

    [SerializeField]
    private float m_StepWidth = 1f;

    private Mesh m_Mesh;

    // questionable if you need this in Update EVERY FRAME
    // I would probably rather move it to Start and do this ONCE
    private void Update()
    {
        if (!m_End)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!m_MeshFilter)
        {
            m_MeshFilter = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
        }

        if (!m_MeshCollider)
        {
            m_MeshCollider = GetComponent<MeshCollider>();
        }

        // Get the start and end points in local space (because Mesh vertices are in local space)
        // using zero here since as start point we simply use the position of this object itself
        var start = Vector3.zero;
        var end = transform.InverseTransformPoint(m_End.position);
        // if start is higher invert to make it work in both directions
        // (otherwise triangle winding order would be more complex)
        if(start.y > end.y)
        {
            (start, end) = (end, start);
        }

        // Get the overall vector from start to end
        var delta = end - start;

        // Project the delta vector onto the XZ plane to get the forward direction
        var forward = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(delta, Vector3.up).normalized;

        // Calculate the right direction by taking the cross product of the forward direction and the up direction
        var right = Vector3.Cross(Vector3.up, forward);

        // Calculate the required number of steps
        var stepCount = Mathf.CeilToInt(Mathf.Abs(delta.y / m_MaxStepHeight));

        // Calculate the step distance
        var stepDistance = delta / stepCount;

        // Setup the mesh data
        var vertices = new Vector3[stepCount * 8]; // 1 cube = 8 vertices per step
        var triangles = new int[stepCount * 36]; // 1 cube = 6 faces = 12 triangles = 36 vertex indices  per step

        var rightStep = Mathf.Abs(m_StepWidth * 0.5f) * right;
        var upStep = Vector3.up * stepDistance.y;

        for (var i = 0; i < stepCount; i++)
        {
            var stepStart = start + stepDistance * i;
            var stepEnd = start + stepDistance * (i + 1);

            // Calculate the vertices for the current step
            var vertexStartIndex = i * 8;
            vertices[vertexStartIndex + 0] = stepStart - rightStep; // Front bottom left
            vertices[vertexStartIndex + 1] = stepStart - rightStep + upStep; // Front top left
            vertices[vertexStartIndex + 2] = stepStart + rightStep + upStep // Front top right
            vertices[vertexStartIndex + 3] = stepStart + rightStep; // Front bottom right

            vertices[vertexStartIndex + 4] = stepEnd - rightStep - upStep; // Back bottom left, note the negative Y because stepDistance already includes the Y
            vertices[vertexStartIndex + 5] = stepEnd - rightStep; // Back top left
            vertices[vertexStartIndex + 6] = stepEnd + rightStep; // Back top right
            vertices[vertexStartIndex + 7] = stepEnd + rightStep - upStep; // Back bottom right

            // Calculate the triangles for the current step
            // 6 faces of a cube per step
            // 2 triangles for each face
            var triangleStartIndex = i * 36;

            // Front face
            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 0] = vertexStartIndex + 0;
            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 1] = vertexStartIndex + 1;
            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 2] = vertexStartIndex + 2;

            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 3] = vertexStartIndex + 0;
            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 4] = vertexStartIndex + 2;
            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 5] = vertexStartIndex + 3;

            // Back face
            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 6] = vertexStartIndex + 4;
            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 7] = vertexStartIndex + 6;
            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 8] = vertexStartIndex + 5;

            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 9] = vertexStartIndex + 4;
            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 10] = vertexStartIndex + 7;
            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 11] = vertexStartIndex + 6;

            // Top face
            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 12] = vertexStartIndex + 1;
            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 13] = vertexStartIndex + 5;
            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 14] = vertexStartIndex + 6;

            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 15] = vertexStartIndex + 1;
            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 16] = vertexStartIndex + 6;
            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 17] = vertexStartIndex + 2;

            // Bottom face
            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 18] = vertexStartIndex + 0;
            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 19] = vertexStartIndex + 7;
            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 20] = vertexStartIndex + 4;

            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 21] = vertexStartIndex + 0;
            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 22] = vertexStartIndex + 3;
            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 23] = vertexStartIndex + 7;

            // Left face
            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 24] = vertexStartIndex + 0;
            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 25] = vertexStartIndex + 5;
            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 26] = vertexStartIndex + 1;

            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 27] = vertexStartIndex + 0;
            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 28] = vertexStartIndex + 4;
            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 29] = vertexStartIndex + 5;

            // Right face
            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 30] = vertexStartIndex + 3;
            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 31] = vertexStartIndex + 2;
            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 32] = vertexStartIndex + 6;

            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 33] = vertexStartIndex + 3;
            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 34] = vertexStartIndex + 6;
            triangles[triangleStartIndex + 35] = vertexStartIndex + 7;
        }

        // Create mesh instance if doesn't exist
        if (!m_Mesh)
        {
            m_Mesh = new Mesh
            {
                name = "Stairs",
                indexFormat = UnityEngine.Rendering.IndexFormat.UInt32
            };

            // assign to according components
            m_MeshFilter.mesh = m_Mesh;
            m_MeshCollider.mesh = m_Mesh;
        }

        // update the mesh
        m_Mesh.Clear();
        m_Mesh.vertices = vertices;
        m_Mesh.triangles = triangles;
        m_Mesh.RecalculateNormals();
        m_Mesh.RecalculateBounds();
    }
}
```

[image]